# dataLayer variable isn't dynamically changing inside GTM custom HTML tag

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

```
<script>
   console.log({{bounce_checker}});
   (function(){
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload',checker, false);})();
   function checker(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log(event.type);
   console.log({{bounce_checker}});
   var validator = {{bounce_checker}};
   if(validator == "value_lead")
    {console.log('value_lead');}
   else if(validator == undefined)
    {console.log('bounced_user');}   
   </script>
```

The above code is deployed as custom HTML tag in DOM ready event. At the time when it fires {{bounce_checker}} dataLayer variable will be undefined but it's setup to change after a user interaction. When 'beforeunload' event happens, the {{bounce_checker}} is to display 'value_lead' if there was any user interaction else 'bounced_user'.

But the data Layer variable isn't dynamically changing. its always showing up as 'undefined' just the way it was during the DOM event.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

with this code, you add a listener that utilizes the value of {{bounce checker}} ar the moment when the listener was created e.g. undefined. GTM will not update that variable since it's not a regular js object but an expression that evaluates to some value.
Consider switching to pushing some event to dataLayer on 'beforeunload' and processing your {{bounce checker}} value at custom HTML tag triggered by custom event, something like:

```
<!--DOM Ready Custom HTML Tag code -->
<script>
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(e) {dataLayer.push({'event':'beforeunload'})}, false);
</script>

<!--beforeunload Custom Event Custom HTML Tag code -->
<script>
  console.log({{bounce_checker}});
  var validator = {{bounce_checker}};
  if(validator == "value_lead") {
    console.log('value_lead');
    // further processing of {{bounce_checker}} value
    // ...
  }
  else if(validator == undefined) {
    console.log('bounced_user');
    // further processing of {{bounce_checker}} value
    // ...
  }   
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Дмитро Булах. That makes sense. I also had other workarounds which solved my issue like manually parsing through the dataLayer using for...loop or forEach loop.



Also, in GTM community forums, Simo Ahava had suggested me to use 

`var validator = window.google_tag_manager[{{container_ID}}].dataLayer.get('bounce_checker');`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Дмитро Булах. That makes sense. I also had other workarounds which solved my issue like manually parsing through the dataLayer using for...loop or forEach loop.

```js
    (function() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', checker, false);
    })();
    
    function checker(event) {
        console.log(event.type);
        console.log({
            {
                bounce_checker
            }
        });
        var i;
        var arr = window.dataLayer;
        for (i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
            if (typeof(arr[i]) === 'undefined') {
                console.log('caught error')
            } else if (arr[i].bounced_user) {
                var validator = arr[i].bounced_user;
            } else {}
        };
        console.log({
            {
                bounce_checker
            }
        });
        console.log(validator);
        if (validator == "value_lead") {
            console.log('value_lead');
        } else if (validator == undefined) {
            console.log('bounced_user');
        }
        console.log('testing success');
    }
```

Also, in GTM community forums, Simo Ahava had suggested me to use

```
var validator = window.google_tag_manager[{{container_ID}}].dataLayer.get('bounce_checker');
```